# File browsing in Android

Tags: android, file-browser

Is there a specific View/Widget available for browsing files on the device? Or is there another solution that has become accepted? Searching has yielded very little useful information for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no special View/widget for browsing files. But it's not very difficult to write it yourself. Googling would find number of public sources/intents for file browsing. General idea is simple: just use `File.listFiles()` and fill appropriate `ListView` keeping in mind SD card root and phone FS root.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I imagined the answer to be.